# Discrete Mathematics Proof,

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a problem where I need to prove the following:

[image]

So far what I did was:

1. take the contrapositive of this statement.

Which becomes: $a|b \land a|(b+1) \implies a\leq2$

2. Using a fact of divisibility:

$a|(2b+1) \implies a\leq2$

At this point I am stuck, any advice or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: If $a\mid b$ and $a\mid b+1$ then $a\mid 1$, taking the difference $(b+1)-b=1$.

Comment: Hi Dietrich, Thank you for your comment. I don't quite understand what you mean by ,taking the difference. Would it be possible to explain further? I don't think you mean `a|(b+1)` - `a|b`

Comment: We have $a|b$, $a|c$, so $a|-c$, so $a|b+(-c)$ and thus $a|b-c$.

Comment: Think about your contrapositive. If $a|b$ and $a|(b+1)$, that means that $b$ and $b+1$ (which are consecutive integers) are both multiples of $a$. How can it happen that two multiples of $a$ occur right next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know in general that $x|y$ and $x|z$, we also know that $x|y-z$. (You can derive this like so: $y=kx$, $z=lx$, $y-z=kx-lx=(k-l)x$, thus $x|y-z$.)
When $a|b$ and $a|b+1$, we thus know that $a|(b+1)-b=1$. That can only be true if $a=\pm 1$. Since $-1<2$ and $1<2$, we now know that $a\geq 2$ implies that $a|b$ and $a|b+1$ can't both be true at the same time.

Comment: Hi Ragnar, thank you for the response. I am wondering, why must a be positive? I am confused on that aspect of the proof. The problem states `for all a in the set of integers`

Comment: @AA, Oh, I overlooked that. I'll edit it.

Comment: Thank you for the update Ragnar. I was also wondering: shouldn't it be a<=2 not a<2?

Comment: We know that $b$ and $b+1$ are an even and an odd number. Since $2$ only divides even numbers, it can't divide both $2$ and $3$, and thus the theorem is true for $a=2$.

Comment: Thank you I understand. However doesn't this violate DeMorgan's law? I understand why it should be `a<2` but negating a>2 gives me a<=2. It feels slightly awkward to simply take out the equality.

Comment: It is still true when it is stated as $a>2$. It only makes the theorem weaker (it is a 'special case' of the theorem I proved). The theorem doesn't really say anything about the case $a<2$, so there is no new stuff to be proven when you change it to $a\leq 2$.